# C# WPF - How to acces controls added in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to change properties of a control which was added in code (Window_Loaded Event). Each one has unique name generated during creation.
I want to change IsChecked property for specific CheckBoxes.

Here is a code which I use to add those CheckBoxes:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            sp.Name = "StackPanel_" + x.ToString();
            sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
            {

                CheckBox rb = new CheckBox();

                rb.Name = "rb_" + x.ToString() + "_" + y.ToString();
                rb.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
                rb.IsEnabled = false;
                rb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                sp.Children.Add(rb);

            }

            Grid.SetRow(sp, x);
            Grid.SetColumn(sp, 1);
            GridBits.Children.Add(sp);
        }
```

Comment: After checboxes are created i read read data from serial port. Based on data from serial i want to change IsChecked property - simple visualisation of bits. By that time i no longer have acces to rb object.

Comment: but is is the part i do not have yet. i have 8 integer variables and i want to show them i a form of checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you want a 8x8 cell with each cell contains a checkbox to represent 1 bit.
You can maintain a 8x8 Array:

```
CheckBox[,] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[8,8];
```

Then add the Checkbox with x and y in your code into this list

```
boxes[x,y] = rb;
```

According to the bits received, you can relocate it easily with x,y coordinate